Can something other than God be necessary being(other than abstract objects), like non-physical metaphysically systems?
In the Leibnizian and Aquinas Cosmological argument(contingency), it is mentioned that there is 2 types of beings, one is contingent and the other one is necessarey being. Theists usually say if there is necessary existant it is God. My question is can something other than God be necessary being like necessary systems which non-physical, is able to create universe, eternal, has the same attributes as god but it does not have mind, it has no consciousness?
Definition of necessary being: It has to exist, impossible to not exist, independent of anything, exists by its own nature.
If you ask how can a being like this create universe, my answer is it can create the universe because of it's own nature.
And is it only possible for God to be the only necessary being except abstract objects?
And can you give me some articles about why God has to be the necessary being.
Thank you.

You ask about possibilities, not about facts. In the domain of possibilities, possibly nature itself is a necessary being.
You define a necessary object as an object whose essence implies

that it exists uncaused in all possible worlds
that it is the creator of the actual world.

The concept is rather entangled. It is not clear how to ground on it a consistent ontology.
Moreover and more substantial: Centuries of philosophical discussion show that we lack the conceptual tools and principles to deal with questions like these in a rational way.

Sir I actually defined it. Necessary being is eternal, is not caused by anything, is not dependant on anything, it has to exist in all possible worlds.

@Hido You are right. I apologize. I edited my answer now.

Thank you sir for answering preciate you.

Sir can we say that if such thing like necessary being exists, a necessary system which isno mind and exists by it's own  nature can be real?    And do you know arguments/articles about why God can be the only necessary being sir? Btw what I mean by necessary system is, necessary system is pretty much same as god, and it is non-physical but the only difference between god and system is, God has mind, system doesn't...

@Hido I apologize for non entering into a discussion about God. I consider the God-concept to be one of the most problematic and misleading concepts invented by theologians and also by philosophers with a strong religious affinity. The last section of my original answer indicates: I do not expect any progress when mixing up philosophy with theological concepts. – I am curious whether any other participants of the present site take up your question. See also the links to similar themes at the right-hand margin on this page. Possibly you may ask your original question on a religious forum, too.

No problem sir, thank you for answering. The reason why I don't ask it ib religious forum is they usually don't know about Philosophy, they know the holy book. Well some of the participants do know but not lot of them, that is why I am here sir.

Why would nature be a necessary being? This reminds me of the Copleston-Russel debate. How is nature defined such that it satisfies the condition of necessity, because in most definitions it is conceptually contingent?

The question is ill-formed. We can ask whether something is necessary, or whether it is not necessary, but it doesn't mean anything to ask whether it can be necessary. That which can be, can be not; that which can be not is not necessary.
Normally approaching questions about being by starting with questions about possibility is a good beginning, so it feels natural to begin investigating necessary being the same way. But it is simply not an option. Instead we have to determine whether there is a necessary being - which we can then name God, like Aquinas does, if we feel like it, although I would rather not - then start trying to work out what its properties are. We can assign the properties probabilities which reflect our own ignorance, but the probabilities would describe our own ignorance about that being which must be, not different possible beings which could be or be-not.

Sir possibilities are good for it I guess. I am just asking is it logically possible that something other than god, but just same as god except it doesn't have mind be a necessary being?

I answered a very similar question here:  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/114818/29339
Short answer
Yes, it is at least plausible that something other than a God could be necessary.
It is therefore a burden of justification on a theist making a necessity argument, to show how a God (a conscious agent with major or omnipotent power) is the only possible kind of necessary thing.
Longer answer
The case for ANYTHING being necessary, is generally not made by the philosophers, who instead "postulate" necessity.
As necessity is a VERY strong claim or property, appending it willy nilly to sorts of things that are implausible to be "necessary" is VERY bad philosophizing!
There are so many different varieties of God that have been postulated, it is pretty clear from inspection that not only can not all of them be "necessary" but that NONE of them are necessary!  IF our world had a God or Gods, WHAT the God or Gods is like is very clearly a contingent question!
The secular alternatives proposed to be necessary, of a universe, laws of physics, etc. -- are also about as clearly contingent as something is possible to be.  Cosmology models, and new proposed laws of physics, are proposed willy nilly all the time in physics and cosmology journals!  None of them are derivable from some first principle of logic -- they are explicitly and essentially contingent!
Summary
Yes, IF the method of arbitrarily appending "necessary" to a proposed thing was actually a valid practice, THEN it could be done with other things besides Gods.
BUT it is not a valid practice.  Gods and universes are not rationally demonstrable to be necessary.  They are instead contingent hypotheses, to be studied empirically.

thank you for your answer sir, can I ask you few more questions?

@Hido you are interested in more dialog than comments allow, so I have created a chat room.  @ me to get my attention.  Here is the room  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/154509/discussion-on-omnipotence-and-necessity
